# Change string split select SQL query into update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split a column in a SQL table into two columns where the data in the column is separated with a “-”, I have managed to edit a query I found online to do that.

The issue is, it only returns the data for viewing as it is a `select` query.

How can I change this query to update the table?

```
select
case when CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)>0 
     then SUBSTRING(ProjectNumber,1,CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)-1) 
     else ProjectNumber end ProjectNumber, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)>0 
     THEN SUBSTRING(ProjectNumber,CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)+1,len(ProjectNumber))  
     ELSE NULL END as Vessel
from dbo.Stock
```

EDIT:

I have tried this:

```
update dbo.stock set vessel =
 case when CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)>0 
 then SUBSTRING(ProjectNumber,1,CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)-1) 
 else ProjectNumber end **ProjectNumber,**
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)>0 
 THEN SUBSTRING(ProjectNumber,CHARINDEX('-',ProjectNumber)+1,len(ProjectNumber))  
 ELSE NULL END as Vessel
```

But it is telling me i have a syntax error near `ProjectNumber`, it's the one i put stars around.

Comment: Seems straight forward to me. What column to update? What value to put in it? More details please

Comment: What have you tried?  Assuming you have a field named `vessel` in your `stock` table, this is just a simple `update` statement -- `update dbo.stock set vessel = your case statement`.

Comment: When updating your fields, you can only update a single field to a single value.  And don't use column aliases at the end of the case statement (remove `as vessel`).  `update table set field = case ... end, field2 = case ... end`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use the STRING_SPLIT function? (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples):

```
UPDATE dbo.Stock
SET vessel = id1,
    vessel2 = id2
FROM (
 SELECT id, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 value as val 
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(id, '-')  
  ORDER BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1 ASC)) ASC
  ) AS id1, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 value as val 
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(id, '-')  
  ORDER BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1 ASC)) DESC
  ) AS id2
 FROM dbo.Stock
) A inner join dbo.Stock  B
ON A.id = B.id;
```